# python count ocurrences in a tuple of tuples

Tags: python-3.x

I have a tuple with tuples inside like this:

```
tup = ((1,2,3,'Joe'),(3,4,5,'Kevin'),(6,7,8,'Joe'),(10,11,12,'Donald'))
```

This goes on and on and the numbers don't matter here. The only data that matters are the names. What I need is to count how many times a given name occurs in the tuple and return a list where each item is a list and the number of times it occurs, like this:

```
list_that_i_want = [['Joe',2],['Kevin',1],['Donald',1]]
```

I don't want to use any modules or collections like Counter. I want to hard code this.
I actually wanted to hardcode the full solution and not even use the '.count()' method.

So far what I got is this:

```
def create_list(tuples):
   new_list= list()
   cont = 0
   for tup in tuples:
       for name in tup:
           name = tup[3]
           cont = tup.count(name)  
           if name not in new_list:
               new_list.append(name)
               new_list.append(cont)
   return new_list


list_that_i_want = create_list(tup)
print(list_that_i_want)
```

And the output that I am been given is:

```
['Joe',1,'Kevin',1,'Donald',1]
```

Any help? Python newbie here.

Comment: Your code currently throws a NameError, please include your **current** code.

Comment: Even after fixing the NameError, it still throws an IndexError

Comment: I fixed the typos. Sorry for that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could. create a dictionary first and find the counts. Then convert the dictionary to a list of list.

```
tup = ((1,2,3,'Joe'),(3,4,5,'Kevin'),(6,7,8,'Joe'),(10,11,12,'Donald'))
dx = {}
for _,_,_,nm in tup:
    if nm in dx: dx[nm] +=1
    else: dx[nm] = 1
    
list_i_want = [[k,v] for k,v in dx.items()]

print (list_i_want)
```

You can replace the for_loop and the if statement section to this one line:

```
for _,_,_,nm in tup: dx[nm] = dx.get(nm, 0) + 1
```

The output will be

`[['Joe', 2], ['Kevin', 1], ['Donald', 1]]`

The updated code will be:

```
tup = ((1,2,3,'Joe'),(3,4,5,'Kevin'),(6,7,8,'Joe'),(10,11,12,'Donald'))

dx = {}
for _,_,_,nm in tup: dx[nm] = dx.get(nm, 0) + 1
    
list_i_want = [[k,v] for k,v in dx.items()]
print (list_i_want)
```

Output:

```
[['Joe', 2], ['Kevin', 1], ['Donald', 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using an intermediary dict:

```
def create_list(tuple_of_tuples):
   results = {}
   for tup in tuple_of_tuples:
       name = tup[3]
       if name not in results:
           results[name] = 0
       results[name] += 1
   return list(results.items())
```

Of course, using defaultdict, or even Counter, would be the more Pythonic solution.

Comment: It definitely works but the result that it's been given is a list with tuples as each item. What I want is a list with [[name, times]]. Right now your code gives: [tuple, tuple, tuple].

Answer (score 0):

Here, a no-counter solution:

```
results = {}
for t in tup:
    results[t[-1]] = results[t[-1]]+1 if (t[-1] in results) else 1
results.items()
#dict_items([('Joe', 2), ('Kevin', 1), ('Donald', 1)])
```

Comment: I see. Thanks but I wanted to hardcode the solution myself. I wrote that in the question. :)

Comment: This is a very common and trivial exercise. Unless you want an efficient solution, SO would not be a good place to ask this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this approach:

```
tuples = ((1,2,3,'Joe'),(3,4,5,'Kevin'),(6,7,8,'Joe'),(10,11,12,'Donald'))
results = {}

for tup in tuples:
    if tup[-1] not in results:
        results[tup[-1]] = 1
    else:
        results[tup[-1]] += 1

 new_list = [[key,val] for key,val in results.items()]
```